# Manipulando Array em PHP

Tags: php, array

Estou criando um PHP que cria graficos usando o Google Charts, mais não consigo abastecer a função com todos os dados da array.
Quando eu imprimo a função, ao invés dele imprimir todos os estados da array, ele imprime apenas o primeiro.
Segue como estou fazendo:

```
$query = "SELECT estado, count(*) as quantidade FROM tb_participacoes where id_campanha = ". $id_campanha ." GROUP BY estado";

$mostrar = mysql_query($query);

while ($produto = mysql_fetch_array($mostrar)) {
$valores = $produto['estado'];
$referencia = $produto['quantidade'];
}
$grafico = geraGrafico(500, 200, array($valores), array($referencia)) ;
```

Comment: Teste usando `[]` depois de valores, assim: `$valores[] = $produto['estado'];`

Answer (score 2):

No `while` que tem no seu código você está sempre a sobrepor o valor de `$valores` e `$referencia` a cada iteração, penso que quer usar essas variáveis como arrays.

Nesse caso deve usar assim (note os `[]` extra no código):

```
while ($produto = mysql_fetch_array($mostrar)) {
    $valores[] = $produto['estado'];
    $referencia[] = $produto['quantidade'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o Sergio mencionou, utilize [] nas variáveis valores e referencia. Depois, ao chamar o gráfico, passe o array:

```
$grafico = geraGrafico(500, 200, $valores, $referencia);
```

Comment: Porquê o voto negativo?

Comment: ?? Não votei negativo. Até agora, não fiz um voto negativo no stackoverflow em português

Comment: A minha pergunta não era para tí :) Era para quem votou a tua resposta negativo, eu gostava de saber porquê.

Comment: @Sergio Ah tá, entendi errado. Realmente, fiquei sem saber o porquê :P